# Getting Error Repository syntax error "insert dimension to compelete refrenceType

Tags: java

```
public interface AllCitiesRepository extends JpaRepository<AllCities, int>{
    
@Query("SELECT C FROM AllCities C WHERE C.AllCities = ?1")
    List<AllCities> findAll();
}
```

Getting error "insert dimension to compelete refrenceType" Please help me out .

Comment: Well, at least `int` is a primitive type, which is not allowed as a generic type.

Comment: so whats the solution for this? need to change in model int to intger ?

Comment: Just use the wrapper type [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html).

Comment: Okey Thanks for quick help. it means a lot .Thank you  very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least `int` is a primitive type, which is not allowed as a generic type.

The error is caused by using a primitive type, which cannot be used as a generic type argument. For instance, `List<boolean>` is incorrect, whereas `List<Boolean>` is correct. Wrapper classes can be used to wrap the primitive values and yield a reference type, which in turn can be used with generics.

#### But why this strange error message?

The message "Insert dimensions to complete expression/referenceType" is probably because in order for the expression to become valid, the *only* valid token here is a set of square brackets.

For instance,

```java
… extends JpaRepository<AllCities, int[]>
```

will just compile fine. In Java, [all arrays are objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1), even arrays of primitive types.